# Можно ли скачать VS с данной опцией?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установка данной опции требует скачивание >2GB с инета. На данной машине такой возможности нет. Можно ли скачать сразу готовый пакет с этой опцией, чтобы можно было поставить на эту машину?

upd: VS 2015

Comment: А разве в iso-образ она не входит?

Comment: Надо будет дома посмотреть.

Comment: Эм.. А что ты смотрел перед тем, как задать вопрос?

Comment: Установленную VS community English. Образа нет сейчас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qwertiy прав. Данная опция входит в образ. Скачать можно по ссылке
[Скачать VS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)